# can't build android APK due to SDK_INT and VERSION_CODES.P - what is that?

Tags: java, android, gradle

It's been two sad days trying to release my React Native app for Android, but getting this error:

```
> Task :react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/myuser/project/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java:368: error: cannot find symbol
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable P
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/myuser/project/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java:370: error: cannot find symbol
        locationEnabled = mLocationManager.isLocationEnabled();
                                          ^
  symbol:   method isLocationEnabled()
  location: variable mLocationManager of type LocationManager
Note: /Users/myuser/project/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My `project/android/build.gradle` file is:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
        playServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.1"
            }
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 27
            buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

            defaultConfig {
                targetSdkVersion 27
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.0"
}
```

Also, my Android Studio has the following components downloaded:

- API 27
- API 28
- Android SDK Build Tools 29
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform Tools
- Android SDK Tools
- Support Repository

I tried several times cleaning gradle cache, but no success.
I'm a newbie on java and have no idea on how to deal with this.

Any idea?

---

After changing compiledSdkVersion to 28, now I'm getting the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Cannot find a version of 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
        Constraint path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' strictly '1.1.0' because of the following reason: releaseRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
        Constraint path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' strictly '1.1.0' because of the following reason: releaseRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
        Constraint path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' strictly '1.1.0' because of the following reason: releaseRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0

> Could not find com.android.support:collections:27.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
      project :app > com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0
> Could not find com.android.support:cursoradapter:27.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
> Could not find com.android.support:loader:27.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0
      project :app > com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0
> Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0
   > Cannot find a version of 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' that satisfies the version constraints:
        Dependency path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
        Constraint path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' strictly '1.1.0' because of the following reason: releaseRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
        Constraint path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' strictly '1.1.0' because of the following reason: releaseRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
        Constraint path 'MobileApp:app:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel' strictly '1.1.0' because of the following reason: releaseRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0

> Could not find com.android.support:versionedparcelable:27.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0
> Could not find com.android.support:documentfile:27.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0
> Could not find com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:27.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0
> Could not find com.android.support:print:27.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0
```

---

UPDATE 3

After changing `details.useVersion` to `28.0.0` I'm now getting this error:

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
> Could not list contents of '/Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/.bin/sane'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `compileSdkVersion` is 27, but Android P is API 28. You need to set your `compileSdkVersion` to 28 if you'd like to use Android P specific APIs, such as the `Build.VERSION_CODES.P` constant, which was only introduced in Android P.

As per [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd), you should always seek to compile with the latest SDK (whether you use any features of that API level or not).

Prior to the [Migration to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), Lint does complain if you use a Support Library version that does not match your `compileSdkVersion`. You can either ignore it, or upgrade to `28.0.0`, which was the last release prior to moving to AndroidX.

Comment: thanks for explanation! I made the change and now I'm getting different errors... could you please help?

Comment: Did you update your `resolutionStrategy.eachDependency` block to use `28.0.0`?

Comment: changed it now and updated post with new error message

Comment: also, do I have to change `buildToolsVersion` and `supportLibVersion` as well?

Comment: It looks like this is another problem, so I'll consider your answer as correct and maybe open another question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, I'd certainly find/replace all `27.1.1` with `28.0.0` if you want to upgrade. Best of luck!